# Market app crashes when I try to scroll

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab, bugs

For the last day or two I have had trouble in the default Market application.

When I try to scroll in the "Just In" area the application just stops working. I get a black screen for while then I get an error that `process com.android.vending` has crashed.

My device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab and I get crashes in all "Just In" sections such as "Just In" in games, apps/tool etc.

What it could be?

Answer (score 3):

I would try and clear the cache of this application

- menu
- Settings
- Applications
- Manage Applications
- All
- Market
- Clear cache

Just to see whether this should help.

You might also want to click the 'Clear data' button but than you must login to your account again.

Comment: I did it even before I asked my question but becouse lack of my English I did not mentoed that. But no help still no scrol

Comment: @adopilot: Try install AppDroid http://www.appbrain.com/app/appbrain-app-market/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps . You can at least install and lookup software . See if this works.